# Is it possible to convince Swing to cache images loaded using a <img> tag in a jTable cell, instead of re-downloading the image on each repaint?

Tags: java, swing

As the title says, I've noticed that remotely-hosted images loaded using `<img>` tags inside a jTable cell's content are re-downloaded each time the component is repainted. The cell's contents would look something like `<html><img src="http://www.example.com/image.png"></html>`

Normally, this isn't much of an issue, though with large enough images and with components that repaint themselves often enough it can both become a performance issue to the application (as it will freeze while the image is re-downloaded each time the component is repainted), and possibly a request spam/bandwith issue for whichever poor file server is hosting the image.

Is it possible to convince Swing to only download the image the first time it's needed and then re-use the cached copy when repainting instead of redownloading it every time?

**And to clarify, the way I noticed this behaviour was by:**

1. Noticing the clear performance drop when rapidly repainting the jTable cell while a large image is being rendered on it.
2. Hosting said image file on a Netty file server and seeing the console output look like this: 
   [Pages and pages of this, and more appearing rapidly as the component is repainted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cBtJ.png)

Edit, Adding a MCVE to the question:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] argv) {

        JFrame demoFrame = new JFrame("Table");

        JTable jTable = new JTable();

        demoFrame.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(jTable));

        DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel(new Object[]{"cache test"}, 5);

        jTable.setModel(dtm);

        jTable.setValueAt("<html><img src=\"https://i.imgur.com/zfa0mEn.png\"></html>", 2, 0);

        demoFrame.pack();
        demoFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

It'd be a bit tedious and excessive to also throw in a file server of some sort to keep track of the file requests here aswell, so I've decided against it.

Comment: You could cache the images yourself and then use an absolute local file path to render them using html

Comment: @GhostCat I've added a MCVE to the question, thank you.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Not sure why it didn't occur to me that img tags could also load local files, thank you for the advice. I've solved the problem now in a way that atleast suits my needs, I'll be adding it as an answer incase it helps someone else.

Answer (score 2):

I've found a way to solve the problem, might not be the prettiest but it did solve both the performance problem and the unnecessary spam-requesting of the same image.

The following code contains both the MCVE and a `TableModelListener` implementation that will automatically detect when image tags are put into the contents of any of the jTable's cells, locally download the image to a folder created on the working directory of the application, and then replace the  tag's src attribute to point to that cached file instead.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelListener;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] argv) {

        JFrame demoFrame = new JFrame("Table");

        JTable jTable = new JTable();

        demoFrame.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(jTable));

        DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel(new Object[]{"cache test"}, 5);

        jTable.setModel(dtm);

        jTable.getModel().addTableModelListener(new ImageCachingTableModelListener());

        jTable.setValueAt("<html><img src=\"https://i.imgur.com/zfa0mEn.png\"></html>", 2, 0);

        demoFrame.pack();
        demoFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static class ImageCachingTableModelListener implements TableModelListener {

        String regex = "<html>(?:[\\s\\S]*)<img(?:[\\s\\S]*)src=\"((?:[\\S]+)\\/([\\S]+\\.[A-Za-z0-9_-]+)(?:[\\s\\S]*))\"(?:[\\s\\S]*)?>(?:[\\s\\S]*)<\\/html>";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);

        @Override
        public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent evt) {
            DefaultTableModel evtTableModel = (DefaultTableModel) evt.getSource();

            if (evt.getType() == TableModelEvent.UPDATE) {

                for (int i = evt.getFirstRow(); i <= evt.getLastRow(); i++) {
                    String content = (String) evtTableModel.getValueAt(i, evt.getColumn());
                    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(content);

                    if (m.find()) {

                        String imageSrc = m.group(1);
                        String imageFileName = m.group(2);

                        try (InputStream in = new URL(imageSrc).openStream()) {
                            File cacheDir = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "imgcache");

                            if (!cacheDir.exists()) {
                                cacheDir.mkdirs();
                            }

                            Path cachedFilePath = Paths.get(cacheDir.getCanonicalPath() + File.separator + imageFileName);

                            Files.copy(in, cachedFilePath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);

                            evtTableModel.setValueAt(content.replace(imageSrc, "file:" + cachedFilePath.toString()), i, evt.getColumn());

                        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks for the help, hope this is of use to someone else. Thanks to 
[artemis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9931982/artemis) for his help with the regex part of the code.

Comment: Nice self answer!